# Validando Login

Tags: c#, validação, login

Estou tentando fazer acesso login, porém não estou conseguindo fazer uma coisa.

Primeiro verifico se os campos usuário e senha estão preenchidos. Até ai tudo bem. Depois verifico se a senha e o usuário estão corretos. E caso Estejam corretos ele vai abrir um novo formulário.

Porém gostaria de fazer com que quando eu digitasse no campo senha 123(que seria uma senha correta) ele não abrisse o formulário e sim que ele executasse o último `if` para que eu cadastrasse uma nova senha. E ai sim, o formulário iria abrir quando eu logasse com a nova senha.

Estou meio perdido e não sei se usei os `ifs` e os `elses` corretamente.

Meu Código:

```
private void btnentrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((txtLogin.Text == "") || (txtsenha.Text == ""))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Digite Usuário e Senha!");
        txtLogin.Focus();

    }
    else
    {
        clnlogin login = new clnlogin();
        OracleDataReader objDados;
        objDados = login.ListarLogin(txtLogin.Text);
        if (objDados.Read())
        {
            login.Usuario = objDados["usuario"].ToString();
            login.Senha = objDados["senha"].ToString();
            if (txtsenha.Text != login.Senha)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Senha Inválida", "ocorreu um Erro ao autenticar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtsenha.Clear();
                txtsenha.Focus();
            }

            else
            {
                frmPrincipal x = new frmPrincipal();
                this.Visible = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Bem Vindo ao Sistema" + "," + txtLogin.Text);
                x.Show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Usuário Incorreto!");
            txtLogin.Clear();
            txtsenha.Clear();
            txtLogin.Focus();
        }

        if ((txtsenha.Text == "123"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cadastre sua Nova Senha!");
            txtsenha.Enabled = false;
            txtLogin.Enabled = false;
            lblnovasenha.Visible = true;
            txtnovasenha.Visible = true;
            btnsalvar.Visible = true;
            btnCancelar.Visible = false;
            btnentrar.Visible = false;
            txtnovasenha.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: É só colocar of 'if' da senha no começo do primeiro else.

Answer (score 1):

Evite usar muitos if's else aninhado, parta do princípio que se tiver muitos, há uma grande probabilidade de seu código ter erro de lógica.

Não testei, mas tente assim:

```
private void btnentrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((txtLogin.Text == "") || (txtsenha.Text == ""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Digite Usuário e Senha!");
            txtLogin.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if ((txtsenha.Text == "123"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cadastre sua Nova Senha!");
            txtsenha.Enabled = false;
            txtLogin.Enabled = false;
            lblnovasenha.Visible = true;
            txtnovasenha.Visible = true;
            btnsalvar.Visible = true;
            btnCancelar.Visible = false;
            btnentrar.Visible = false;
            txtnovasenha.Focus();
            return;
        }

        clnlogin login = new clnlogin();
        OracleDataReader objDados;
        objDados = login.ListarLogin(txtLogin.Text);
        if (!objDados.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Usuário Incorreto!");
            txtLogin.Clear();
            txtsenha.Clear();
            txtLogin.Focus();
            return;
        }

        login.Usuario = objDados["usuario"].ToString();
        login.Senha = objDados["senha"].ToString();
        if (txtsenha.Text != login.Senha)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Senha Inválida", "ocorreu um Erro ao autenticar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            txtsenha.Clear();
            txtsenha.Focus();
            return;
        }

        frmPrincipal x = new frmPrincipal();
        this.Visible = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Bem Vindo ao Sistema" + "," + txtLogin.Text);
        x.Show();
    }
```

Comment: `Evite usar muitos if's else aninhado` levem esse conselho para a vida. Só pra constar, o Linus Torvalds tem o costume de passar horas escrevendo insultos pessoais para todos aqueles que submetem código para o Kernel do Linux com mais de quatro níveis de indentação. If's aninhados então recebem todo um "carinho e atenção" especial dele.

Answer (score 1):

Se você informar que o usuário ou a senha especificamente estão incorretas, fica fácil para alguém mau intencionado tentar invadir sua aplicação. Fiz algumas alterações a fim de reduzir código.

```
private void btnentrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLogin.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtsenha.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Digite Usuário e Senha!");
        txtLogin.Focus();
        return;
    }

    if (txtsenha.Text == "123")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cadastre sua Nova Senha!");
        txtsenha.Enabled = false;
        txtLogin.Enabled = false;
        lblnovasenha.Visible = true;
        txtnovasenha.Visible = true;
        btnsalvar.Visible = true;
        btnCancelar.Visible = false;
        btnentrar.Visible = false;
        txtnovasenha.Focus();
        return;
    }

    clnlogin login = new clnlogin();
    OracleDataReader objDados;
    objDados = login.ListarLogin(txtLogin.Text);

    login.Usuario = objDados["usuario"].ToString();
    login.Senha = objDados["senha"].ToString();
    if (txtsenha.Text != login.Senha || !objDados.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Usuário ou Senha inválido", "ocorreu um Erro ao autenticar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txtLogin.Clear();
        txtsenha.Clear();
        txtLogin.Focus();
        return;
    }

    frmPrincipal x = new frmPrincipal();
    this.Visible = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Bem Vindo ao Sistema" + "," + txtLogin.Text);
    x.Show();
}
```